# Probability of certain ordering of people around a round table

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given $20$ people - $10$ males and $10$ females that are sitting around a round table.
Find the probability for which the order of the sitting is the following:
Between any pair that consists of $2$ females, there is at least one male.
For example a valid sitting order can be of the form:

$\langle$female,female,male,female,female,male,male,female,female,male,female,female,male ...$\rangle$

The answer should be one of the following:
(a) $ 0.0655 $

(b) $ 0.0131 $

(c) $ 0.0027 $

(d) $ 0.0014 $
I tried combining each pair of females into one and finding the number of arrangements around the table to get an upper bound for the answer, but I am getting a number which is lower than the options which available, this is what I did:
$\displaystyle{\frac{\displaystyle{10 \choose 2}2!14!}{19!}}$
There are $\displaystyle{10 \choose 2}$ ways to split the females into groups of $2$, because the order matters here I multiplied it by $2!$, then I multiplied by the number of ways to arrange $15$ people around a round table which is $(15-1)!$ but I am getting a number which is lower than the options for the answer in the question so I'm stuck.
I'll appreciate any insights, thanks !

Comment: Your example of a "valid sitting order" has some cases of ...female,female... and in such a case there is not "at least one male" between that particular pair of females.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you I fixed it now, indeed if we are starting with a female we will have to end with a male

Comment: @SalmonFish can you please elaborate on what you did ?

Comment: what was the source of the problem?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the arrangement should be (f,m,f,m,f,m....)?

Comment: @DS I might have translated the question bit wrong, anyway the source is from a probability and statistics course at the Open University of Israel (original question: https://ibb.co/NtH2qLp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hand each man a chair and have the men wait while we seat the women.

In a circular permutation, only the relative order matters. Suppose Anna is one of the females.  Seat her.  We will use her as our reference point.

There are nine ways to choose another female to sit adjacent to Anna and two ways to choose on which side of Anna that person sits.  Once they are seated, there are $8!$ ways to arrange the other eight females as we proceed clockwise around the table from the pair that includes Anna.  Doing so determines the other four pairs of females.

Now that we have set the pairs, this creates five gaps in which to place the ten males.  Let $x_i$ be the number of males in the $i$th gap as we proceed clockwise around the table from Anna.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the positive integers.  A particular solution of Equation 1 corresponds to the placement of four addition signs in the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones.  For instance,
$$1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 3, x_3 = 2, x_4 = 3, x_5 = 1$.  The number of solutions to Equation 1 is the number of ways we can place $5 - 1 = 4$ addition signs in the $10 - 1 = 9$ gaps between successive ones in a row of ten ones, which is
$$\binom{10 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{9}{4}$$

Now that we have decided how many males are in each gap, there are $10!$ ways to arrange the ten males in those gaps.

Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$9 \cdot 2 \cdot 8! \cdot \binom{9}{4} \cdot 10! = 2 \cdot 9! \binom{9}{4} 10!$$

Since there are $19!$ ways to arrange the other $19$ people as we proceed clockwise around the table from Anna, the probability that there is at least one male between each of the five pairs of adjacent females is
$$\frac{2 \cdot 9! \dbinom{9}{4}10!}{19!} \approx 0.0027$$

Comment: oh, so the problem meant "divide the 10 females into 5 pairs, and between 2 pairs, set at least one man!". Although, how did you get the $9$ in $\color{blue}9\cdot 2 \cdot 8! \cdot \binom{9}{4} \cdot 10! $?

Comment: @DS Once you seat one woman, there are nine women left who can be paired with her.

Comment: oh, right. I'd forgotten about her (+1)

Answer (score 3):

- Step $1-)$ Separate the females into groups of size $2$ by $$\frac{\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{5!}=\frac{10!}{2^5 \times 5!}$$
- Step $2-)$ Place the $5$ groups around the table by $(5-1)!$
- Step $3-)$ Females can interchange in each pair by $2!$ ways , so there are $2^5$ possible arrangements.
- Step $4-)$ We can disperse $10$ male into $5$ gaps where there is at least one male in each gaps using stars and bars such that $C(5+5-1,5)=C(9,4)$ ways , but the males were distinct , so multiply by $10!$.

**Result:** $$\frac{\frac{10!}{2^5 \times 5!} \times 4! \times 2^5 \times C(9,4) \times 10!}{19!}=0.00272791..$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig do you see my error in my answer , why my answer gave wrong one ?

Comment: It seems the wording was not clear.  Yarin meant that the females should be arranged in five pairs, with at least one male between each pair.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig exactly, five pairs of females (each of size 2) and between them at least 1 male

Comment: With the correct interpretation of the problem, the answer I am getting matches (c).  Your error lies in your count of $\frac{10!}{2^5} \cdot 4! \cdot 2^5 = 10!4!$ ways of arranging the ten females, which is clearly too large.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig i must have grouped them

Comment: It seems you initially forgot that your groups were not labeled.  Kudos for finding that error.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes , silly mistake.. thanks for allocating time for me

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the correct interpretation of the problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only way in which between every pair of females there is at least one male is the alternating sequence $M, F, M, F, ...$. As @coffeemath mentioned in the comments, the given "example" does not work, since there is no $M$ between

$$\color{red}{F, F}, M, \color{red}{F, F}, M, M, \color{red}{F, F}, M, \color{red}{F, F}, M, ...$$

The total number of seatings around a circular table, where we don't care to distinguish seatings that are rotationally equivalent, is simply $(N - 1)!$, since we assume someone is already seated and count permutations of the remaining people.

For the genders to alternate, assume some male is already seated. Next to him, we must seat a female, from which there are $\frac{N}{2}$ to choose from. Next to her, we choose one of the $\frac{N}{2} - 1$ remaining males, and so on. The number of ways is

$$\frac{2}{N} \left( \left( \frac{N}{2} \right)! \right)^2$$

When $N = 20$, this probability is

$$\frac{\frac{1}{10} (9!)^2}{19!} = \frac{1}{9237800} \approx 1.083 \times 10^{-7}$$

Comment: It seems that Yarin meant that the females should be arranged in five pairs, with at least one male between each pair of pairs of females.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Interesting, that is definitely *not* what the question explicitly stated!

Comment: I initially interpreted the problem the same way that you did.  Yarin corrected my interpretation.